# Duplicate question of same user

Tags: support

I have found two question which are duplicate from same user.

[Ubercart product quantity count in product view page show as smsung 2/10 sold?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94083/ubercart-product-quantity-count-in-product-view-page-show-as-smsung-2-10-sold)

[How do I configure the Stock module in and know how many products are sold out of stock?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/how-to-configure-stock-module-in-ubercart-and-know-how-many-products-sold-out-of/94206#94206)

I have answered one of his question and he accepted this.

Initially OP asked to configure "Stock" and then added some comment which make his question to duplicate to another question.

Now, I would like to know if should I need to answer another question or need to suggest OP in comment to check another question.

Comment: These don't look like dups to me, but I may be missing something.

Comment: @MPD, after adding comment of OP in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/how-to-configure-stock-module-in-ubercart-and-know-how-many-products-sold-out-of/94206#94206 "how many products sold out of stock?", it seems both are similar. But, my question is that we need to answer both question or we can answer one question and add link in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they aren't duplicates, since [Ubercart product quantity count in product view page show as smsung 2/10 sold?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94083/ubercart-product-quantity-count-in-product-view-page-show-as-smsung-2-10-sold) is asking about any module to use to achieve what the OP wants, while the other question is asking how to use the Stock module. Eventually, from [How do I configure the Stock module in and know how many products are sold out of stock?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/how-to-configure-stock-module-in-ubercart-and-know-how-many-products-sold-out-of) I would take the OP found a module to use, but that doesn't mean the OP would like to know if there are other modules to use.

If anything should be said about [How do I configure the Stock module in and know how many products are sold out of stock?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94204/how-to-configure-stock-module-in-ubercart-and-know-how-many-products-sold-out-of) is that it doesn't show any effort to find the answer, nor does it show any any understanding of the problem from the OP's side; it just states the OP doesn't know how to use that module, which would make me wonder if the OP did read the documentation.

A lack of research could cause the question to be down-voted, but I am not sure that automatically makes the question one of those to be closed.

Comment: If you will check comment section in ` How do I configure the Stock module in and know how many products are sold out of stock?`, then you will find the OP is asking how to display product count and sold item of the product?

Comment: Yes, but that comment is written the day after, right before to ask the other question. It doesn't mean the OP was already using the Stock module. Even if they were already using the Stock module, one question is asking what module the OP could use; you could think they are already using the Stock module, and they want to use another module. The other question is asking how to set the Stock module; that doesn't mean they found a module to use, and answering the other question is not anymore necessary.

Comment: OK. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

In general, duplicate questions should be closed.  If you have the [privilege to case close votes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), do so.  If enough people agree, it will be closed.  If you don't, you can flag as duplicate, and a moderator will take a look.  Just remember that we close duplicate *questions*.  If two different questions have the same answer, they aren't necessarily dups.

In this specific case, I would defer the flag to another mod.  To me, it doesn't look like an exact duplicate, but I am not positive enough to dismiss it.

If you feel they are different *questions*, then answer it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Initially question was not similar but OP add comment in one question which he asked as question in another, so I feel both are similar.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola if comment was needed to clarify, then you can ask OP to edit it into a question. If he will, and it will make questions dupes, flag as dupes. If he will not, flag as unclear / too broad. If comment was not needed, point OP to a question where he already has answer for that comment ;)

Comment: @Mołot, Ok. I have already asked OP to update question but he did not do. I will follow your next guide.